# Buck converter with some big ripples

Tags: power-electronics, buck

I am simulating a buck converter (schematic at the end) ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm61495)) and I observe bigger spikes in addition to the normal ripple. In the screenshot below, Vout is in green and the buck converters SW output is in red. It is clear that the spikes in Vout corelate with the change in SW but I am unsure which one is the cause.

[image]

Questions:

1. What's the reason for those spikes? Where are they coming from?
2. What can I do to make those spikes smaller? Is there something besides adding more capacity?

Schematic:
[image]

Edit: added link to datasheet

Edit 2: See a similar effect with a 10uH inductor below
[image]

Edit 3: 10uH simulation zoomed out
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a load step?

Comment: @winny no, the load is a constant 1 Ohm resistor

Comment: Try making L1 something like 10 uH and report back. Add a link for the data sheet too.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a plot with a 10uH inductance to the question. The datasheet is linked aswell

Comment: If the load was less, it could perhaps kick in and out of skip cycle or some light load power saving feature, but 500 mA is too high for that. Strange. Can you zoom out? Does it repeat at some fixed interval?

Comment: @mlx11 what maximum timestep have you got set up? It should be a small fraction of the switching period (like about 1%)? Not sure how to set it in LTSpice if that's what you are using. Aha it's under "edit simulation command/transient" (just found it).

Comment: @winny I edited the question with the zoomed-out screenshots. It is definitely not fully random but there's no clear pattern either.

Comment: @Andyaka I am using PSpice for TI with the default settings. The field is empty (for default). What do you think would be an appropriate step size to rerun the simulation with?

Comment: I just realized that I have RELTOL (tolerances on voltages) set to 0.01 instead of 0.001 (default). I am rerunning the simulation with all the settings to default right now.

Comment: Increasing the simulation accuracy (not the step size) made those spikes diapear. Is this a sign of instability or insufficient phase margin of my feedback loop?

Comment: It will be called **maximum** step size and zero is likely a crappy default value for your simulation.

Comment: I'm no expert on PSpice that you use but it certainly looked like a "settings" problem. Try and find the maximum step size feature too and set that appropriately. For decent accuracy it should noticeably slow-down the speed and, of course, we all accept this if the result is a much better quality result @mlx11